# angular2 how to unit test pipe needing mock service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for a Pipe that takes in an object as a parameter. This object is created from a mock service.

Is it possible to use a mock service when unit testing a pipe? Do I have to include the component that uses the pipe in the test?

**PIPE** - this pipe basically takes in an object and a set of arguments. Based on the arguments it manipulates the object parameter and returns it.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(myData: models.MyInfo, args: string[]): string { //stuff here }
}
```

**MOCK SERVICE** - the mock service queries object array which is used in the parameter of the pipe.

```
@Injectable()
export class MockMyService {
getMyInfo(){
//logic
}
```

**EXAMPLE OF PIPE USE IN COMPONENT** - below is an example of how it's used

```
this.xObj = this.realService.GetInfo();     
this.myList = this.myPipe.transform(this.xObj[0], ['a', 'b', 'c',]).split(',');
```

**UNIT TEST THAT I TRIED** - I've tried a couple of things. the code below shows how I've tried to couple the Component and Pipe, and also trying to test the pipe without the component.

```
//core dependencies
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed }  from "@angular/core/testing";
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA }           from '@angular/core';
import { By }                         from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }               from '@angular/core';
import { RouterTestingModule }        from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpModule }                 from '@angular/http';
import { DatePipe }                   from '@angular/common';

//pipe, component being tested
import { MyPipe } from './path to pipe';
import { ComponentThatUsesPipe } from '../path to the component';

//models / other
import { MOCKEDOBJECT } from '..path'

//services
import { MockMyService } from '..path to service';
import { RealService } from '..path to real service';

describe('myPipe', () => {
  let pipe = new MyPipe();
  let component: ComponentThatUsesPipe ;

  var myDetailsArray: models.ObjDetails[] = MOCKEDOBJECT ;
  var myDetails: models.ObjDetails;
  var myList: string[] = [];


  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ComponentThatUsesPipe, MyPipe],
      providers: [{provide: RealService, useClass: MockMyService}]
    });
    component = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentThatUsesPipe ).componentInstance;
  });

  this.myList = pipe.transform(this.myDetails.m[0], ['a','b',1,2,3]);

  it('test1', () => {
     expect(this.myList.findIndex(s => s.trim() === 'Med') > -1).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

My test return an error of 'cannot read property of m '.

**Edit - was able to resolve based on advice from 'estus' comments below**

```
describe('myPipe', () => {
  let pipe = new myPipe();
  let myDetailsArray: models.ObjDetails[] = MOCKEDOBJECT;
  let myDetails: models.ObjDetails = myDetailsArray[0];
  let hasA: boolean = false;
  let hasB: boolean = false;
  let hasC: boolean = false;
  let myList: string[] = [];

  this.myList = pipe.transform(myDetails.member[0],[stuff here]).split(',');
  this.hasA = (this.myList.findIndex(s => s.trim() === 'M') > -1);
  this.hasB = (this.myList.findIndex(s => s.trim() === 'P') > -1);
  this.hasC = (this.myList.findIndex(s => s.trim() === 'D') > -1);

  it('test myPipe hasA', () => {
     expect(this.hasA).toBe(true);
  });

  it('test myPipe hasB', () => {
     expect(this.hasB).toBe(true);
  });

  it('test myPipe hasC', () => {
     expect(this.hasC).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

Comment: `myDetails` is not defined. `this.myDetails` is not defined. Even `this` is not defined if you're using strict mode (and you should).

Comment: noted. thanks. so, if the this.myDetails needs to be defined by the MockMyService how do I go about that? is it in the beforeEach(() => {}... ?

Comment: It shouldn't be defined at all. You're using arrows. `this` is `window` in loose mode and `undefined` in strict mode. Assign a value to `myDetails` variable in beforeEach or elswhere. I don't really see what MockMyService is doing in this test. It isn't injected into a pipe.